# Copy video file to iCloud of my friend

Tags: icloud, file-sharing

Can I copy a video file to the iCloud of my friend from my MacBook ? Suppose I know the AppleId and the password.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by 'to the iCloud'? iCloud Drive? Shared Photo Stream? iCloud Photo Library?

Comment: The "iCloud" AppleTV has access to. I want my friend to play my video file in her AppleTV.

Answer (score 1):

When your freind has a mac or iOS device with airdrop, you can send it to him without any wires.

On your macbook you can use the share-button (square with arrow in it) to share the file. There should be numerious ways to share a video.

I think it is notossible to import a video directly to someones icloud unless it is enabled on your mac.